# ACADO Toolkit MPC based robot controller weird behaviour around obstacles

Tags: ros2, rviz, diff-drive-controller, obstacle-avoidance, mpc

I have been strugling with this issue for a long time now, any help would be appreciated.

So, I have a robot simulation running in Gazebo. I have implemented a robot controller that follows a direct path (red arrows in video).

The problem that I'm facing, is that the controller works perfectly when there are no obstacles, or even if an obstacle is near it. However, when the robot is right next to the obstacle, it seems like it's stuck. It is just continuously driving forwards to the obstacle and then backwards away from it. The idea is, that the MPC would find a path around the obstacle and not through it. This correctly happens, if the robot is further away, and the planned path is through it.

What I mean is seen in the following GIF:

[image: Visual representation]

Using the following MPC parameters:

```
N: 10
Ni: 5                          # Number of integration steps
DT: 0.4
Q: [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.0, 0.6]   # Weights for: x, y, psi, v, obsticles
R: [0.8, 0.8]                  # Weights for: acc, df
```

The simple robot model used by MPC is defined as:

```
    ACADO::DifferentialState x_dv;
    ACADO::DifferentialState y_dv;
    ACADO::DifferentialState psi_dv;
    ACADO::DifferentialState v_dv;
    
    ACADO::Control acc_dv;
    ACADO::Control df_dv;

    ACADO::DifferentialEquation f;
    
    f << dot(x_dv) == v_dv * cos(psi_dv);
    f << dot(y_dv) == v_dv * sin(psi_dv);
    f << dot(psi_dv) == df_dv;
    f << dot(v_dv) == acc_dv;
    
...
    
    // Modeling obstacles using ellipses
    // https://www.desmos.com/3d/198ca551a0
    for (size_t i = 0; i < max_obstacles; i++) {
      Obstacle obs;
      auto obs_expression =
        pow((x_dv - obs.h), 2) / pow((obs.a / 2.0) + robot_radius, 2) +
        pow((y_dv - obs.k), 2) / pow((obs.b / 2.0) + robot_radius, 2);

      obs_expression = exp(1.0 / obs_expression) - 1;
      obstacle_cost += obs_expression;
      obstacles.push_back(obs);
    }

...
    
    ACADO::OCP ocp(0, N * DT, N);
    // dynamics
    ocp.subjectTo(f);
    // control constraints with jerk
    ocp.subjectTo(min_acc_dv <= acc_dv <= max_acc_dv);
    ocp.subjectTo(min_df_dv <= df_dv <= max_df_dv);

...

    mpc.set(HESSIAN_APPROXIMATION, GAUSS_NEWTON);
    mpc.set(DISCRETIZATION_TYPE, MULTIPLE_SHOOTING);
    mpc.set(INTEGRATOR_TYPE, INT_EX_EULER);
    mpc.set(NUM_INTEGRATOR_STEPS, N * Ni);
    mpc.set(SPARSE_QP_SOLUTION, FULL_CONDENSING);
    mpc.set(QP_SOLVER, QP_QPOASES);
    mpc.set(HOTSTART_QP, YES);
    mpc.set(GENERATE_TEST_FILE, YES);
    mpc.set(CG_USE_OPENMP, YES);
    mpc.set(GENERATE_MAKE_FILE, NO);
    mpc.set(CG_USE_VARIABLE_WEIGHTING_MATRIX, YES);
    mpc.set(FIX_INITIAL_STATE, YES);
```

In the controller loop, input values are set as follows:

1.) Set *y* and *yN* matrices to values of the reference path (red arrows in GIF) 
2.) Set *od* matrix of OnlineData h, k, a, b to ellipses of obstacles. 
3.) Set *x0* matrix to values of current robot x, y, psi and speed calculated from last state + acc * dt 
4.) Set first row of *x* matrix to *x0* and all the other rows to calculated states from previous ACADO step. 
5.) Set *u* matrix to calculated states from last ACADO step. 
6.) Account for Yaw discontinuity, by mapping *x* and *y* yaw values to be continious. when compared with x0.
7.) Perform a step.

In case this helps, here is one of the inputs into the MPC:

```
Differential variables:
       x_dv            y_dv            psi_dv           v_dv
[
    3.151049e-02    1.669996e-02    6.472188e-02    -1.313597e-01
    -2.848066e-02   1.206563e-02    9.400955e-02    -1.810388e-01
    -9.376713e-02   5.240898e-03    1.233946e-01    -1.387157e-01
    -1.392330e-01   -6.990173e-04   1.511286e-01    -7.850582e-02
    -1.624499e-01   -4.187169e-03   1.745280e-01    -2.897570e-02
    -1.683534e-01   -4.992846e-03   1.924457e-01    6.245024e-03
    -1.611267e-01   -3.304897e-03   2.050393e-01    3.696647e-02
    -1.402863e-01   1.264299e-03    2.127804e-01    7.786711e-02
    -1.003729e-01   1.001139e-02    2.157023e-01    1.385549e-01
    -3.538515e-02   2.420534e-02    2.140740e-01    2.078960e-01
    5.022709e-02    4.271929e-02    2.120098e-01    2.355843e-01
]


Reference variables:
       x_dv            y_dv            psi_dv           v_dv           acc               df           obstacle
[
    3.151049e-02    1.669996e-02    2.000483e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
    1.518622e-01    4.110251e-02    2.000483e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
    2.722139e-01    6.550506e-02    2.000483e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
    3.925655e-01    8.990761e-02    2.000483e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
    5.129172e-01    1.143102e-01    2.000483e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
    6.332689e-01    1.387127e-01    2.000483e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
    7.536206e-01    1.631153e-01    2.000483e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
    8.739723e-01    1.875178e-01    2.000483e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
    9.943240e-01    2.119204e-01    2.000483e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
    1.114676e+00    2.363229e-01    2.000483e-01    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00
]


Control variables:
        acc              df
[
    -1.275384e-01   7.321918e-02
    1.058078e-01    7.346272e-02
    1.505246e-01    6.933483e-02
    1.238253e-01    5.849856e-02
    8.805182e-02    4.479427e-02
    7.680362e-02    3.148401e-02
    1.022516e-01    1.935271e-02
    1.517194e-01    7.304655e-03
    1.733528e-01    -4.070535e-03
    6.922068e-02    -5.160679e-03
]
```

And the outputs of the system:

```
Computed controls:
        acc              df
[
    -5.348593e-02   6.581785e-02
    1.422513e-01    6.311511e-02
    1.637436e-01    5.973691e-02
    1.223046e-01    5.200674e-02
    7.576451e-02    4.221945e-02
    5.423637e-02    3.249958e-02
    6.906699e-02    2.302529e-02
    1.125932e-01    1.247921e-02
    1.473303e-01    1.007157e-03
    6.260711e-02    -2.222532e-03
]


Computed states:
       x_dv            y_dv            psi_dv           v_dv
[
    3.151049e-02    1.669996e-02    6.472188e-02    -1.313597e-01
    -2.429595e-02   1.248279e-02    9.104902e-02    -1.527540e-01
    -7.603864e-02   7.342682e-03    1.162951e-01    -9.585350e-02
    -1.037078e-01   4.049640e-03    1.401898e-01    -3.035607e-02
    -1.080170e-01   3.669859e-03    1.609925e-01    1.856576e-02
    -9.596168e-02   5.985614e-03    1.778803e-01    4.887156e-02
    -7.337017e-02   1.040641e-02    1.908801e-01    7.056611e-02
    -4.136998e-02   1.687775e-02    2.000903e-01    9.819290e-02
    4.154516e-03    2.628152e-02    2.050819e-01    1.432302e-01
    6.947772e-02    3.988368e-02    2.054848e-01    2.021623e-01
    1.525777e-01    5.714995e-02    2.045958e-01    2.272051e-01
]
```

If more code is needed, I'll be happy to provide it. 
Any help with this issue will be much appreciated! 
Thanks!